# упорядочить выравнивание кода в notepad++

Tags: html, css, notepad++

Как с помощью клавиатуры упорядочить выравнивание кода в notepad++?

пример

```
          html, body {
                     height: 100%  ;
       margin:      0     ;
               padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: [Notepad++ plugin for auto format Css](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28525131/2881286)

Comment: А можно было бы просто WebStorm поставить и Ctrl+Shift+L.

Comment: работал с веб сторм и php сторм , деньги стой и не чем не лутше

Comment: и зачем -1 ставить .....

Comment: Можно подключить плагин: [https://sampawno.ru/viewtopic.php?t=79]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вручную только, выделяешь и shift+tab

Answer (score 1):

Встроенной поддержки автоформатирования кода в notepad++ нет. Но есть плагины. Для CSS может подойти [JSONViewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/). Notepad++ не совсем подходит для реального программирования.

Comment: не подходит ? вы о чём ? посмотрите тысячи мануалов в ютубе от гуру php , js  phyton и увидите на чём американщина работает ! ни каких лобстеров и прочих IDE , только notepad++ и всё , я же в свою очередь пользуюсь только sublime но чаще Gedit

Comment: @Geyan Sublime то и я использовал для JS. Notepad++ использую в основном для замены текста по регулярным выражениям. Любые попытки хоть как-нибудь использовать его для написания кода у меня заканчивались сообщением об ошибке и вылетом программы. Я решил не мучаться с настройкой и использовать IDE, там все есть  из коробки и удобно.

Comment: @Geyan кому как конечно, у каждого свой опыт и потребности.

Comment: @Geyan использование специализированных сред для разработки существенно облегчает сам процесс

Comment: Конечно кому что , но когда я был на windows я не пользовался вообще ни чем кроме notepad++ и жирный минус Линуксу что для него нету NP++ но есть альтернативы не хуже ! Многие любят усложнять `себе жизнь`

Comment: @Geyan По мне так вы себе усложняете жизнь))

Comment: я работаю на node++ потомушто мне надо подключаться к серверу какие есть альтернативы ?  наподобе visual studio ?

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov  да уж ! уже не сколько раз были соревнования по обычному html css у нас в городе и потом + ко всему не много php , 2 раза я занимал первое место из за скорости , так что ....

Comment: @Geyan, разрешите полюбопытствовать, а как выглядят соревнования по html/css/php?)

Comment: @Geyan делать что-то быстро и делать качественно — разные вещи. Не путайте их.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму  как будут такие же я приглашу , приедите в Караганду ?